# pageslide plugin does not fire postback

Tags: c#, jquery, postback

I'm using the [PageSlide](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide) plugin. I added a form to the div#modal, ASP label and a button.
However, the button just doesn't fire a postback event upon click.

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.pageslide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <script src="js/jquery.pageslide.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
 <a href="#modal" class="second">Show</a>
 <div id="modal" style="display: none">        
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
 </div>
 <p><a href="javascript:$.pageslide.close()">Close</a></p>
 <script>
    $(".second").pageslide({ direction: "left", modal: true });
 </script>
</form>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Its Working";
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You're HTML doesn't seem to be connected to a code behind file. It looks like a static HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the reason for such behavior is because plugin clones modal div and use cloned content to show modal popup. Thus, the `Button1` doesn't placed in form anymore and doesn't causes postback on click.  Try to set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` button's property. This way postback should be fired via javascript instead of defaulr submit button's behavior

Comment: thanks, it works now but does not when I add the label and button inside an UpdatePanel. Any pointers??

Comment: @Fahad, try to put a label only into UpdatePanel and register button as AsyncPostNackTrigger

Comment: tried that, it does not work correctly :( what happens is the value of the label does not change upon button click, but after button click, if I hide and show the pageslide pane again, the value of the label changes.. I think I'll have to look into the plugin code in more detail..

Comment: @Fahad, ok the problem is still the same - plugin clones elements to show them modal. So, though label in update panel got new text, the cloned label shown in modal view left unchanged. You can refresh label's text from button's click handler with `RegisterStartupScript.RegisterStartupScript` method and use script like this: `string.Format("$('#{0}').text('{1)');", Label1.ClientID, Label1.Text)`